# Taking ownership of streambuf/stringbuf data

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream, streambuf

I'd like an interface for writing to an automatically resizing array.  One way to do this is with a generic `std::ostream *`.

Then consider if `ostringstream` is the target:

```
void WritePNG(ostream *out, const uint8_t *pixels);

void *WritePNGToMemory(uint8_t *pixels)
{
  ostringstream out;
  WritePng(&out, pixels);

  uint8_t *copy = new uint8_t[out.tellp()];
  memcpy(copy, out.str().c_str(), out.tellp()];
  return copy;
}
```

But I want to avoid the memcpy(). Is there a way to take ownership of the array in the underlying stringbuf class and return that?

I get the feeling this can't be done using standard library, since the stream buffer might not even be a contiguous array.

Comment: No.  You're not really supposed to hang on to the value returned by c_str() at all.

Comment: There are two subquestions here: (1) How do I extract the `std::string` from a `std::ostringstream`? Starting in C++20, you can use `std::move(out).str()` for that. (2) How do I extract an owning (`delete[]`able) `char*` from a `std::string`? You can't do that, and probably will never be able to. So for your purposes, you must either replace your `void*` with `std::string`, or replace your `stringstream`/`stringbuf` with a custom child of `streambuf` as indicated in the existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC the whole reason stringstream exists (vs strstream) was to sort out the fuzzy questions of memory ownership that would come up by giving direct buffer access.  e.g. I think that change was to specifically prevent what you are asking to do.

One way or another I think you'd have to do it yourself, by overriding the stream buffer.  To answer a similar question I suggested something for [input streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7782037/211160) that wound up getting quite a few upvotes.  But honestly I didn't know what I was talking about then, nor now when I suggest the following:

Hacking up [this link from the web](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/streambufs.html) for doing an "uppercasing stream buffer" to one that just echoes and gives you a reference to its buffer might give:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>

class outbuf : public std::streambuf {
    std::string data;

protected:
    virtual int_type overflow (int_type c) {
        if (c != EOF)
            data.push_back(c);
        return c;
    }

public:
    std::string& get_contents() { return data; }
};

int main() {
    outbuf ob;
    std::ostream out(&ob);
    out << "some stuff";
    std::string& data = ob.get_contents();
    std::cout << data;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure it's broken in all kinds of ways.  But the uppercase-buffer-authors seemed to think that overriding the overflow() method alone would let them uppercase all output to the stream, so I guess one could argue that it's enough to see all output if writing to one's own buffer.

But even so, going one character at a time seems suboptimal...and who knows what overhead you get from inheriting from streambuf in the first place.  **Consult your nearest C++ iostream expert for what the actual right way is.**  But hopefully it's proof that something of the sort is possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use the old, deprecated `<strstream>` interface, this is fairly easy - just create a `std::strstreambuf` pointing at your storage, and it will work by magic.  `std::ostrstream` even has a constructor to do this for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <strstream>

int main()
{
    char copy[32] = "";

    std::ostrstream(copy, sizeof copy) << "Hello, world!"
        << std::ends << std::flush;

    std::cout << copy << '\n';
}
```

With the more modern `<sstream>` interface, you need to access the string stream's buffer, and call `pubsetbuf()` to make it to point at your storage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    char copy[32] = "";

    {
        std::ostringstream out{};
        out.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(copy, sizeof copy);

        out << "Hello, world!" << std::ends << std::flush;
    }

    std::cout << copy << '\n';
}
```

Obviously, in both cases, you'll need a way to know in advance how much memory to allocate for `copy`, because you can't wait until `tellp()` is ready for you...

Comment: neat trick, but my output size is unknown (hopefully less than uncompressed size). But I think you're on to something. Can you use pubsetbuf() or set some internal variable to NULL to fool streambuf into thinking there's no memory to deallocate?

Comment: I think the only reasonable option would be to implement a buffer yourself - inherit from `std::basic_stringbuf` with a `std::vector` as storage - read about [`setp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/setp) for an example using `std::array`.  Because a vector can move its contents when it's resized, you'll need to override `overflow()` to call `setp` after using `push_back` or any other vector method that invalidates iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I ended up using. The idea is the same as the one proposed by HostileFork - only needing to implement overflow(). But as already hinted, it has much better throughput by buffering. It also optionally supports random access (seekp(), tellp()).

```
class MemoryOutputStreamBuffer : public streambuf
{
public:
    MemoryOutputStreamBuffer(vector<uint8_t> &b) : buffer(b)
    {
    }
    int_type overflow(int_type c)
    {
        size_t size = this->size();   // can be > oldCapacity due to seeking past end
        size_t oldCapacity = buffer.size();

        size_t newCapacity = max(oldCapacity + 100, size * 2);
        buffer.resize(newCapacity);

        char *b = (char *)&buffer[0];
        setp(b, &b[newCapacity]);
        pbump(size);
        if (c != EOF)
        {
            buffer[size] = c;
            pbump(1);
        }
        return c;
    }
  #ifdef ALLOW_MEM_OUT_STREAM_RANDOM_ACCESS
    streampos MemoryOutputStreamBuffer::seekpos(streampos pos,
                                                ios_base::openmode which)
    {
        setp(pbase(), epptr());
        pbump(pos);
        // GCC's streambuf doesn't allow put pointer to go out of bounds or else xsputn() will have integer overflow
        // Microsoft's does allow out of bounds, so manually calling overflow() isn't needed
        if (pptr() > epptr())
            overflow(EOF);
        return pos;
    }
    // redundant, but necessary for tellp() to work
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132458/why-does-the-standard-have-both-seekpos-and-seekoff
    streampos MemoryOutputStreamBuffer::seekoff(streamoff offset,
                                                ios_base::seekdir way,
                                                ios_base::openmode which)
    {
        streampos pos;
        switch (way)
        {
        case ios_base::beg:
            pos = offset;
            break;
        case ios_base::cur:
            pos = (pptr() - pbase()) + offset;
            break;
        case ios_base::end:
            pos = (epptr() - pbase()) + offset;
            break;
        }
        return seekpos(pos, which);
    }
#endif    
    size_t size()
    {
        return pptr() - pbase();
    }
private:
    std::vector<uint8_t> &buffer;
};
```

They say a good programmer is a lazy one, so here's an alternate implementation I came up with that needs even less custom code. However, there's a risk for memory leaks because it hijacks the buffer inside MyStringBuffer, but doesn't free MyStringBuffer. In practice, it doesn't leak for GCC's streambuf, which I confirmed using AddressSanitizer.

```
class MyStringBuffer : public stringbuf
{
public:
  uint8_t &operator[](size_t index)
  {
    uint8_t *b = (uint8_t *)pbase();
    return b[index];
  }
  size_t size()
  {
    return pptr() - pbase();
  }
};

// caller is responsible for freeing out
void Test(uint8_t *&_out, size_t &size)
{
  uint8_t dummy[sizeof(MyStringBuffer)];
  new (dummy) MyStringBuffer;  // construct MyStringBuffer using existing memory

  MyStringBuffer &buf = *(MyStringBuffer *)dummy;
  ostream out(&buf);

  out << "hello world";
  _out = &buf[0];
  size = buf.size();
}
```